# Nothing works wrong but I still get error message

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I made a page exactly the way I wanted it. Somehow compiler show me an error message every time I go to that page. Nothing seems wrong. Everything works perfectly. Why am I getting this error every time?

My code like this;

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Image.asset(
      "assets/someImage.jpg",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SlimyCard(), // It's a package from pub.dev
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    minHeight: 50,
                    maxHeight: 500,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text("Some text"),
                            Text("Some text."),
                            Text("Some text.."),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text("Some text..."),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

I tried remove Expanded on ListView and add somewhere else but everything is breaking down.

Compiler says;

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.
The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#25b39] ← Scrollable ← ListView ← Expanded ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← ⋯)
```

Comment: You can't use `Expanded` in `ListView`

Comment: Using SingleChildScrollView with a Column does not give the result I want. What can I use but ListView here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to understand why the Expanded is needed, as the SlimeyCard will take as much as it needs and no more. why did you initially use the Expanded widget?

the code below works for me, try it and say if you get the same results

```
 return Stack(
  children: [
    Container(height: 1000,width: double.infinity, color: Colors.white,),// instead of the background image
    // Image.asset(
    //   "assets/someImage.jpg",
    //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
    // ),
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SlimyCard(bottomCardHeight: 500,),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  minHeight: 50,
                  maxHeight: 500,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("Some text"),
                          Text("Some text."),
                          Text("Some text.."),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Some text..."),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

Thing about the SlimyCard has a animation and its expanding. If wrap it container with height It's working but does not fit when it expands. With your code I get the result like this.

[picture-one](https://i.imgur.com/wdA28ss.png)
[picture-two](https://i.imgur.com/bR7QV0G.png)

Comment: i downloaded the package just for fun and it works for me. why do you need to wrap the SlimyCard in something? it works smoothly as is. i now updated the answer on this post so try to copy paste it again and id like to hear your  results ^_^

Comment: Hi again Kami,
I didn't understand what happened here but code is working. I showed you the result I got yesterday. I'm confused but thank you very much. Appreciate for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your desired UI is, but I made some changes in your code and it works without error. If this isn't something you want, please share the screenshot of your desired UI.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Image.asset('assets/someImage.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 130, child: Placeholder()), // Replace this with your card.
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    minHeight: 50,
                    maxHeight: 500,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('Some text'),
                            Text('Some text.'),
                            Text('Some text..'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text('Some text...'),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Thing about the SlimyCard has a animation and its expanding. If wrap it SizedBox It's working but does not fit when it expands. Here is my desired UI

[picture-one](https://i.imgur.com/7XDKj7V.png)

[picture-two](https://i.imgur.com/CH1eVbx.png)

Comment: @Emre Thanks, but I never used that package on my own, so I can't help you any more. If you can use any other widget (from the Flutter library itself), please update your post and I'll edit my answer to make it work for you.